# How to automate username and password fields of EDGE browser using Selenium library and Robot framework?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

[image]

How to enter username and Password into EDGE browser pop up window using selenium library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isn't basic authentication? If yes, then submit username and password in url like:

`http://${username}:${password}@${url}`